# code igniter framework guidance for beginners

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks, codeigniter-2

I am just a beginner in `code igniter`. I have just downloaded the code igniter framework. But i don't know that where should i keep my html, php files and stylesheets, images etc. Is there any procedure to do the things? Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

CodeIgniter has an awesome user guide that will come with the install you can read through (or read it online at - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/ ), or you can watch some of the videos on their site - http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/

In comparison to most other frameworks you're going to find they have maybe the smallest learning curve and great documentation. I would also recommend learning basic PHP and getting familiar with your web environment maybe before beginning.

Comment: Those video tutorials are severely dated, I'd avoid learning from them.

Comment: @Ryan's spot on--start with the user guide!

Answer (score 1):

I used these tutorials to help get me started with the framework haven't look back since!  http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/

Answer (score 0):

hi I am a weekend coder and picked up CI about a year ago.

It helped me a lot.

The best tutorial I found was on the IBM's developer site. It runs through putting together a simple application. Admittedly, there's nothing in it about directory and file placement but it helps cement ideas about how models, views and controllers (MVC), and why MVC is so helpful. Because the basic idea is quite simple, it's worth running through a simple CI tutorial again and again till you 'feel' or intuit the basic helpfulness of the setup.

Things like JS, CSS files can be kept in their own folders at the first level of your website folder e.g /js or /css or /images. You ask about PHP files as well. PHP files which you, the coder, write, are either 'views', 'models' or 'controllers'. These go in the folders with those names in the /application folder e.g /application/views/yourview.php or /application/controllers/yourcontroller.php. The CI install comes with a default view file and a default controller, which you are probably already aware of.

The files inside /application/config are important as well. Read the user-guide about tweaking these files. The most obvious tweaks are to database.php to connect to your db, autoload to give automatic use of CI helpers/libraries which you can choose, and to config.php to give CI the name of your website e.g the name you give to '/'.

The file 'index.php' comes with the CI installation (/index.php). You don't need to fiddle with it at all really except to determine the level of error reporting you want ('environment') and that's not a priority at all. But it's important to remember this about index.php - that CI uses it as the essential reference for defining paths to useful folders like CSS or images. So even if your view file is in /application/views, if it refers to an image like a logo.gif in /images for example, the path to it is just /images/logo.gif. It is not anything more complicated like ../../images/logo.gif.

I hope that helps.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Offline version of CodeIgniter  user guide is available with CodeIgniter  which already downloaded by you.

just extract your CodeIgniter  zip file in your localhost server root directory,

Then `http://localhost/www/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/user_guide/` open this url with  browser ,here you can access offline version of CodeIgniter  user guide.

Here I am using wamp server so I used this url, If  you are using xampp server then please use `http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/user_guide/`

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is what I would usually do for code igniter

here is my directory structure.

```
CI App Path (e.g "c:\xampp\htdocs\ci_app_name" )

-application
-system
-assets
--css (new folder , where css files will be included)
--js (javascript and jquery libraries location)
```

Basic HTML and PHP files should be location

```
CI_app_pah

    -application
    --views (this is where to put HTML and PHP files)
```

For other things such as Controller , Models and Views , you can't put any where but put in their related area.

That will be

```
CI app

    -application
    --controllers
    --models
    --views
```